# Sprite movement on mask

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, mask

I have an Avatar class that extends the Sprite class. I also have a Room class that contains a Bitmap of "walkable" areas and non-walkable areas, as well as the room's artwork itself.

I need to make sure that the user can only walk on the white/transparent parts of the room "mask," without actually showing the black and white mask. What functions can I use to ensure that the user doesn't go into the black parts of the mask, quickly?

Comment: Long ago I programmed a ping-pong ball collision with random interior. I added several guard points on the ball's outline and hitTest (in your case that would be bitmap pixel test) these points with the interior graphics.

Comment: Would you give me an example of hit testing with an undo splayed mask like that? Just sample code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to have this 'walkable' bitmap in memory

```
private const ALLOWANCE:Number = .1;
private function isTurnAllowed(maskBMD:BitmapData, position:Point):Boolean
{
    //0xAARRGGBB
    var color32:uint = maskBMD.getPixel32(int(position.x), int(position.y));
    var alpha:uint = color32  >> 24 & 0xff;
    var red:uint = color32 >> 16 & 0xff;
    var green:uint = color32 >> 8 & 0xff;
    var blue:uint = color32 & 0xff;

    var color24:uint =color32 >> 8 & 0xffffff;

    /*
    if (alpha == 0 || color24 == 0xffffff) return true

     strictly speaking this string is enough but in real your bitmap mask after resampling can have some interpolation artifacts so you need some  allowance to pass not strictly white.
     */
    var absoluteLightness:Number = red +  green + blue + (0xff - alpha);//transparent is 0x00
    var maximalLight:Number = 0xff * 4;
    var lightness:Number = absoluteLightness / maximalLight;
    if (lightness > 1 - ALLOWANCE)
        return true
    else
        return false

}
```

Comment: Isn't getPixel32() slow? This executes every time the KeyDown event fires.

Comment: It's slow enough if you need a million operations per frame. But if you need just to check 100-200 positions per second it's ok

 You can check performance by a simple test:<code>  var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1000, 1000, true);
  var pos:Point = new Point(100, 100);
  var lastTime:Number = getTimer();
  for (var i:int = 0; i < 100000; i++)
  {
   var isAllow:Boolean = isTurnAllowed(bitmapData, pos);

  }
  trace(getTimer() - lastTime); //78 millisecond </code>

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your Avatar:Sprite is properly aligned around its own (0,0) point. Then you create a Walkable:Sprite with a shape of walkable areas. It **must** be attached to the display list, but not necessarily visible, you can set Walkable.visible = false.

```
function moveBy(dx:Number, dy:Number):void
{
    var aPoint:Point = new Point();
    aPoint.x = Avatar.x + dx;
    aPoint.y = Avatar.y + dy;

    // hitTestPoint works with Stage coordinates.
    aPoint = Avatar.parent.localToGlobal(aPoint);

    if (Walkable.hitTestPoint(aPoint.x, aPoint.y, true))
    {
        Avatar.x += dx;
        Avatar.y += dy;
    }
}
```

This code is very simple, it just disallows to move your Avatar out of Walkable map.

Comment: What if my avatar is actually a large spritesheet Bitmap that has a scrollRect? Wouldn't this code permit the invisible parts of the spritesheet to collide with the non-walkable areas?

Comment: DisplayObject.hitTestPoint(...) checks a single point by its Stage coordinates. The third argument also specifies to use the actual shape of display object, not the bounding box, that's why Walkable should be a shape fill. I just remembered that I used it in another project: http://delimiter.ru/games/umoria/ The things are a bit more complicated than the script above, as I test multiple points to calculate reflection vector, but the basics are the same.

Comment: What I mean, it is not bounding box vs bounding box collision, it is point vs random shape collision and I think it exactly suits your needs.